Ошибка при подключении к бд sqlite3 python
Код:
import sqlite3
conn=sqlite3.connect(example.db)
cursor=conn.cursor()

И на 2 строке получаю следующую ошибку:

AttributeError: partially initialized module 'sqlite3' has no attribute 'connect' (most likely due to a circular import)

Файл называется не sqlite3.py

а файл с кодом как называется? sqlite3?

У вас ошибка Циклического Импорта.
Циклический импорт может возникнуть, когда два или более модуля импортируют друг друга. Например, если у вас есть два модуля module1.py и module2.py, и они оба импортируют друг друга, это приведет к циклическому импорту.
Пример циклического импорта:
# module1.py
import module2

# module2.py
import module1

Чтобы избежать циклического импорта, убедитесь, что каждый модуль импортирует только те модули, которые ему абсолютно необходимы.
Вы хотите импортировать библиотеку sqlite3, но вместо этого импортируется ваш же файл sqlite3.py, из-за чего и возникает ошибка.
Вам достаточно изменить имя файла с sqlite3.py на любое другое, например, sql3.py.
